# html file to picture on cli of ranger preview

Tags: images, html, ranger

I would like to preview html files in [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) as pictures similarly how pdf files can be previewed. I imagine first it would be needed to force it into A4 page or something of the like, so it's a preview of what would be on your screen when you open it. I could probably set up a pipe going html -> pdf -> picture, but I'm hoping there's a tool out there that can do this directly (so less overhead of two conversions). Does anybody know something like this, or has an elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the [docs](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Official-user-guide#custom-image-previews) on image previewing:

> In recent versions of ranger, the mechanism of the image previews was extended and generalized. When calling scope.sh, ranger sets the $cached environment variable containing a unique path to a file where the image preview may be generated if needed. scope.sh may then save an image to that path and exit with the exitcode 6 (documented inside scope.sh, consult the comment at the top) to tell ranger to use it.
>
> In other words if you can generate a jpg from a file, ranger is able to show a graphical preview for it. Videos, PDFs, all sort of files.

So, edit your `~/.config/ranger/scope.sh`; add a [case to the `handle_image` function](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/v1.9.3/ranger/data/scope.sh#L129):

```bsh
  case "${mimetype}" in
  …
    text/html)
        wkhtmltoimage -f png "${FILE_PATH}" "${IMAGE_CACHE_PATH}" && exit 6
```

You of course have to install `wkhtmltoimage` (which is often in a package called `wkhtmltopdf`).

Haven't tried this, though. Might need to remove `-f png`, or change `-f png` to `-f jpeg` if it doesn't work.

If this does work: be a cool citizen, [fork](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/fork) ranger on github, edit the ranger/data/scope.sh template to include your addition, and open a pull request against upstream ranger, so that others also get your HTML previewer! (although my code isn't complex enough to actually warrant needing this: you get a full right to do [WTF](http://www.wtfpl.net/) you want with the code in this answer)

Comment: made a small correction.

Comment: Perfect, it works, although for the preview you need to add a sensible `--crop-h` otherwise it renders the entire html leading to a veeery long strip in some cases :) We'll definitely do a PR soon :)